# Array - Combine values together

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have the following and would like to get some help in it:

```
function Display($line) {   
    $section = split(" +", $line);   
    for ($i = 1; $i <4; $i+=1){
        $section[$i];
    }       

    $countsection = count($section[3]); 
    $name = "$section[1] $section[2]";
    print "<td>$name</td>\n";
    print "<td>$countsection</td>\n";       
    $endvalue = end($section);       
    print "$endvalue";
}  

$allvalues = file("filename.txt");     
foreach ($allvalues as $checkline) {
   if (ereg("^[[:digit:]]", $checkline)) {
      Display($checkline);         
   }  
 }
```

Here's a basic rundown:

I want

- `$counsection` and `$endvalue` to be counted.  So the values inside `$countsection` need to be added together, the same for `$endvalue.`
- $name needs to be merged together if they're the same $name.

So the following would look something like this:

```
Name |  Count Section |  End Value
Mary Jane |  40 | 156
Tom John |  30  | 60
```

Instead of this:

```
Name | Count Section | End Value
Mary Jane | 10 | 50
Mary Jane | 10 | 50
Mary Jane | 20 | 56
Tom John | 10 | 20
Tom John | 15 | 30
Tom John | 5 | 10
```

File Content Sample:

```
12345    RM  100M 121      T     0400  1059  MWHA 110  Jane, Mary G    40

12345    RM  100M 122       W    0600  1059  MWHA 310  Jane, Mary P     40

12345    RM  100P 110    M  W    0800  0929  CLOU 122  John, Tom    39

12345    RM  100P 210    M  W    0930  1059  CLOU 205  John, Tom    40
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you pulling these from a database? If so, you can group them by `Name` and `SUM` them up in your query. Just a thought..

Comment: What does `var_dump($allvalues)` look like ?? its better to know what your `filename.txt` looks like

Comment: Unfortunately it's not in a database but a single file

Comment: Nina can you add your actual file content  .. it would be easier to work with because your code contains errors such as ` $name = $section[1] $section[2];`

Comment: iterate over the lines and sum up the values - what's the actual question here?

Comment: You are using `$section = split(" +", $line); ` and there is not `+` in the example you gave ..... also which column is the `Count Section`

Comment: Hi Baba, Thanks for looking into this.  The split(" +", $line) the + isn't in file. But I needed it there because if I take it out, I would receive blank values for some reason on my end.  The "Count Section" is the 'fourth' row.

Comment: Last question is `Jane, Mary G` and `Jane, Mary P` the same person or different people

Comment: They would be considered different people. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$allvalues = getValues("log.txt");
print("<table>");
foreach ( $allvalues as $name => $value ) {
    print("</tr>");
    printf("<td>%s</td><td>%d</td><td>%d</td>", $name, $value[0], $value[1]);
    print("</tr>");
}
print("</table>");
```

Output

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Jane, Mary G</td>
        <td>121</td>
        <td>40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jane, Mary P</td>
        <td>122</td>
        <td>40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John, Tom</td>
        <td>320</td>
        <td>79</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Example

```
Jane, Mary G        121         40
Jane, Mary P        122         40
John, Tom           320         79
```

Function Used

```
function getValues($file) {
    $lines = file($file);
    $values = array();
    foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
        $line = trim($line);
        if (empty($line))
            continue;
        $line = explode("  ", $line);
        if (isset($values[$line[11]])) {
            $values[$line[11]][0] += strstr($line[3], " ");
            $values[$line[11]][1] += $line[13];
        } else {
            $values[$line[11]] = array(strstr($line[3], " "),$line[13]);
        }
    }
    return $values;
}
```

Comment: Hi Baba, could you explain how the $values[$line[11]][0] += strstr($line[3], " ");
            $values[$line[11]][1] += $line[13];  works?

Comment: `$a += $b` is the same as `$a = $a + $b` .. it can also be concatenation when dealing with strings like `$a .= $b` = `$a = $a . $b`

Comment: [strstr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) is Find the first occurrence of a string .. i was a looking for a number after the first occurrence of space